# Making Tab appear or disappear onChangeListener on Checkbox in Swing

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, tabs

So I have a UI that I made with Swing using Java. It is very complex and I want to save the user some time by making the UI simpler.
Imagine you have a page with many CheckBox. Once you select whatever CheckBox you desire, the next button makes a JFrame appear with the same tabs as you selected inside a Tabbed Pane.

 Here is a small sample of my code which should give an idea of what I want the button to do:

```
btnNewButton_7.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Admin.set.frame.setVisible(false);
            Admin.adv.setVisible(true);
            Admin.adv.jp2.setVisible(chckbxNewCheckBox_42.isSelected());
            Admin.adv.jp3.setVisible(chckbxNewCheckBox_43.isSelected());
            Admin.adv.jp4.setVisible(chckbxNewCheckBox_44.isSelected());
        }
    });
```

So the next Button should set the JFrame (set.frame) invisible. Then, it should open adv (a new frame). So far, everything is working. Now, my tabe are JPanel inside adv. I would love to make them disappear whenever the CheckBox 42,43 and 44 are selected or unselected, should I add an onChangeListener?

Comment: Try it again after moving `Admin.adv.setVisible(true);` in the end after changing all `jp`s visibility.

Comment: Whenever I see a "next" button on a UI, I immediately think that a CardLayout would be more appropriate than opening/closing separate JFrames.  Have a look at the [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a demo.

Comment: You will need to remove or add the panels to the JTabbedPane, simply making them invisible isn't enough